# batch script to run a command multiple times with different inputs

Tags: batch-file

im new to batch programming...i have a command to unlock a folder and the command should be followed by a password. eg:" unlock 123-456-789 "is used to unlock a folder when it runs on dos env. here "unlock" is the command and "123-456-789" is a password...i have hundreds of passwords in a text file.like 125-897-012, 263-028-782, 584-198-033, etc.i need a batch script to run the command "unlock" and it should take each password at a time to check whether it can unlock the folder...can any1 help me?

Comment: Try running it from the command line and looking at ERRORLEVEL afterwards to see if it changes depending on whether your unlock command worked or did not. Use "echo %ERRORLEVEL%" after the unlock command works and again after it fails and see if it tells you whether the unlock worked. Then look at this... http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 0):

This will run the unlock tool with every password.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("textfile.txt") do (
    echo trying "%%a"...
    call unlock %%a
    cd "c:\locked\folder" >nul 2>&1 && (echo "%%a" seems to work & pause & goto :eof)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much..it works perfectly...i need one more help ...i dont want the command to get executed once it unlocks(i.e when the command uses the correct password from the text file) the folder...but it is executing all the passwords..is the any way to stop the execution after fetching the correct password?

Comment: What do you see on the console?  It is meant to exit once the correct password is found.  I can't test this as I don't have the setup but which version of windows are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...leave that..i need another help...i am working on a project in visual studio 2010 c++ windows application...i need a program which exactly does the same job as hex editor..the input is an image of .raw format. i need to view the image in hex editor..i know there are hex editors available but i need a program to do this..please help me..

Comment: Open a new question, for a new topic.